# How to display image using GCM push notification in android

Tags: jquery, cordova, push-notification, phonegap

I have successed to implement text push notification in android using GCM, but now, i want to put image in status bar when pushing notification, like this :

[image]

i am using jquery and javascript to develop my aps,

here is my manifest:

```
 <activity android:name="com.plugin.gcm.PushHandlerActivity"/>
<receiver android:name="com.plugin.gcm.CordovaGCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
<category android:name="com.example.mypackage" />
```

here is my plugin structure ,

[image]

here is my php to send notification

```
$gbr="http://myWeb/image1.jpg";
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'key');
$registrationIds = array($to);
$msg = array
(
'message' => $message,
'title' => $title,
'vibrate' => 1,
'sound' => 1,
'image'=>$gbr

// you can also add images, additionalData
);
$fields = array
(
'registration_ids' => $registrationIds,
'data' => $msg
);
$headers = array
(
'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
'Content-Type: application/json'
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
```

Answer (score 1):

use picture instead of image

```
$msg = array
(
'message' => $message,
'title' => $title,
'vibrate' => 1,
'sound' => 1,
"style"=> "picture",
"picture"=>"https://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/91615172-find-a-lump-on-cats-skin-632x475.jpg"

// you can also add images, additionalData
);
```

Comment: which plugin you are using in it?

Comment: <plugin name="PushPlugin" value="com.plugin.gcm.PushPlugin" />

Comment: you can use more easy and updated plugin with great explanation https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push